# Unable to run git diff on a file that has moved

Tags: git, diff

Ok the scenario is as follows . . .

1. Move a bunch of files under a new folder in GIT
2. Now I want to view the commit history of one of those files

   - Normally a `git log filename` would suffice
   - Since the file has been moved I can achieve this with `git log--follow filename`
3. The `--follow` commands gives me the full history but I unfortunately I am unable to compare two SHAs in this history for a particular file

For example, I can run a `git diff SHA1 SHA2`: *This will return all the file changes made between these commits*.

However, if I try to bring it down to the file level to compare (`git diff SHA1 SHA2 filename`) it returns nothing !

(Although the previous diff of the SHAs show changes within this file)

Has Anyone come across this before ..

I understand that between the commits this file has moved so I have tried variations like

> git diff --follow SHA1 SHA2 filename

to no avail.

Has anyone else experienced this and if so, do they have a solution to it ?

Answer (score 4):

Another option worth looking into is `-M`. However, in the likely case that this doesn't help, either, you can manually tell git the correct file paths like this:

```
git diff SHA1:path/to/file1 SHA2:path/to/file2
```

(The paths need to be relative to the top level of the repo)